# How to reference the table?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table with some columns:

```
id | age | name | country
1.   18.    Olya.  Moldo
```

I need to store validation result for all columns in separate table like this:

```
Field | valid | validator
18.      True.  Moreequal18
Olya.    True.   IsName
```

How to do that properly?

Comment: This would be tedious indeed. It's not something you would do with SQL normally. This sounds like integration testing or end to end testing - a very large topic. I.e., the literal answer to your question is `update Table2 set valid = 'True', Validator='Moreequal18' where Field = 18 and exists (select * from Table1 where id = 1 and age = 18);`  -- but it would be unfeasible to do this for all your data unless it were only a just a few columns and a few rows to be checked.

Answer (score 0):

You can `UNPIVOT` your table.

But instead of saving the age save the birthdate year, because almost every user gets a year older every year, which you need then to update

> ```
> CREATE TABLE testtable (
>   "id" int,
>   "age" varchar(3),
>   "name" VARCHAR(24),
>   "country" VARCHAR(24)
> );
>
> INSERT INTO testtable
>   ("id", "age", "name", "country")
> VALUES
>   (1,   18,    'Olya',  'Moldo');
> ```

> ```
> SELECT field, True as valid , validator
> FROM testtable t
> JOIN LATERAL (VALUES('Moreequal18', t.age),('IsName', t.name)) s(validator, field)  ON TRUE
> ```
>
> ```
> field | valid | validator  
> :---- | :---- | :----------
> 18    | t     | Moreequal18
> Olya  | t     | IsName
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=610fa6e00ff44f94fc9bfaa6d9e1606e)*